# Insert TextBox into Border

Tags: c#, uwp

how to insert textbox or textblock to border in c#? 
Now I have this:

```
        Border notificationBorder1 = new Border();
        LayoutGrid.Children.Add(notificationBorder1);
        TextBlock notificationTxt1 = new TextBlock();
```

But I don't know how to insert textbox into border. 
I tried to google, but found nothing, just how to change textbox border color.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Just place it inside xaml

```
<Border>
      <TextBlock></TextBlock>
</Border>
```

If you want to do it in the code then just

```
notificationBorder1.Child = notificationTxt1;
```

Comment: Thanks,
I'm trying to create "error or success  notification" TextBlock. Right now I have to copy and paste my xaml to every page that I have.

So I think I'm doing it right. Or it's can be done in a better way?

Comment: Just create your own UserControl and use it on your views/pages where you want to display it. Creating layout controls in the code is denifinitely not a good idea unless you have really good reason to do that